# Wordpress.org support topics returning 404

Tags: 404-error, wordpress.org, support

Recently, in the last day or two (2016 09 28), several Google searches on wordpress topics have sent me to `wordpress.org/support/topic...` like this one: 
[how to add new sidebar in Widgets section](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/207248) that return 404, Page not found.

Does anyone know if there has been a change, or a temporary failure, at wordpress.org/support?

Comment: Support "topics" are threads from the "forum". Just like here on stackexchange they are not guaranteed to exist. It is probably an old link that the site considered no longer valuable.

Comment: obviosly you should ask about the wordpress.org support stuff

Comment: I only asked here because SE in general are better, more active, sites, snarky comments aside, and MOST of the time when I Google an issue and get wordpress.org support threads, they work. Was just hoping someone had more info on my experience of a sudden spate of 404s.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been seeing the same thing; search results for topics on WordPress.org have been 404ing like crazy lately. There's nothing that can be done about it here, but wordpress.org has it's own issue reporting system.  [Please follow up there](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/report/1).

Comment: Thanks @daveromsey. If nothing else,  I can mention that others have noticed the same thing.

Comment: https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2092

Comment: From an update on the link in my previous comment: "To clarify a bit more, WordPress.org support forums were upgraded to bbPress 2.x a few weeks ago (see #1544), and eventually there should be a redirect from old topic URLs, but it hasn't been set up yet, since there are some other issues that have a higher priority"